# How to take the first n items and proceed with remaining in recursion?

Tags: haskell

I want to achieve something like this:

```
f :: [Int] -> [Int]
f (x@[_,_,_,_]:xs) = g x : f xs

g :: [Int] -> Int
g = ...
```

So I want to take the first four items in a list calculate something on them and then do the same thing with the remaining items creating a new list of calculated values. It is like a combination of map and take I guess. Is there something like this in haskell?

I know I could do something like:

```
map g . chunksOf 4
```

I just thought it would look much more "haskelly" with recursion

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`p1 : p2` is a pattern that matches a non-empty list if the list's head matches the pattern `p1` and its tail matches `p2`. `[p1, p2, p3, p4]` is a pattern that matches a four-element list if its elements match p1, p2, p3 and p4 respectively. Thus `[_, _, _, _]:xs` matches a non-empty list if its first element is a four-element list. Since `f` takes a list of ints, not a list of lists, this pattern leads to a type error in your function.

What you want can be expressed as `x1 : x2 : x3 : x4 : xs` and then `where x = [x1, x2, x3, x4]`. Of course that's not particularly pretty and it might be more convenient to just use `take` and `drop` or `splitAt` instead (if you really want to do your own recursion, that is).

> I just thought it would look much more "haskelly" with recursion

I would disagree with that. I'd say it's generally preferable in Haskell to use and combine existing standard library functions instead of writing your own recursive functions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, then I will go with map g $ chunksOf n

Comment: I would just like to ask a sub-question to this as I'm new to Haskell also... Following up on the OPs question I agree that using something like `g :: [Int] -> [Int]` and doing `g(a:b:c:d:xs)` is a good way of extracting the elements, but isn't possible for `n` elements right? I came up with this but I'm not sure if it would be a viable option in this scenario: `g xs = [x*2 | x <- take 4 xs] ++ [x*3 | x <- drop 4 xs]` where `g :: [Int] -> [Int]` and I'm applying basic multiplication to the elements as an example. Of course `4` will be replaced by `n`.

Comment: @px06 Right, you can't use pattern matching when you want to extract a non-constant number of elements. You'll have to use `take` and `drop` like you did.

Comment: @px06 You could do it directly in one pass by subtracting one from `n` each recursive call and then applying the appropriate operation depending on whether `n == 0` or not.

Comment: Better `splitAt` than `take` and `drop`, no?

Comment: @dfeuer Or that, yes.